# Do I need an else clause in a case expression?

Tags: sql, select, hive, case

Does one need to include an `ELSE` clause in a `CASE` expression?

For example, if I wanted to pull the names of animals that are cats and nothing ELSE, could I use this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CASE WHEN animal_type = 'cat' THEN animal_name END) AS cat_names
```

I know I could just put `animal_type = 'cat'` in my `WHERE` clause and then

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_names,
```

but I'd like to know the answer.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*, not a *statement*. Just worth bearing in mind, because people frequently mistake it for some form of flow control statement, rather than being an expression that computes a value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That term probably originated from ORACLE where `CASE` *is* a statement: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You do not **need** an `else` clause. If one isn't specified, `case` will return `null`. In other words, it acts as though it has an `else null` clause.